# Laravel Ajax get request redirect loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I tried to search on documentation about ajax request for laravel, i followed everything but for some reason whenever i add the exact url path on the ajax request, the page keeps refreshing forever...

I checked this documentation https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm

Controller

```
class CardsController extends Controller
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        $client = new Client;
        $response = // Some client

        $body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());
        $cards = $body->Cards;

        // return $cards;
        return response()->json(array('cards'=> $cards), 200);
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/getCards', 'CardsController@getAll');
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {    
    getCards();
});

function getCards() {
        $.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url:'getCards',
           dataType: 'json',               
           success:function(data) {
              $("form").html(data);
           }
        });
}
```

I am using XAMPP and live server on VS Code to test

Comment: What have you tried to check **why** this h appens?

Comment: What do you mean? I looked multiple ajax get requests examples and I don't see anything wrong

Comment: What does your network tab say when the page is refreshing?

Comment: hard to see cause refreshes so fast but something like `Uncaught Type Error. i.attr  is not a function`

Comment: Is the function in your CardsController returning the proper data?

Comment: @NickvanderWaal Yes I tested it iwth `dd()`, even get a full json if i access through url

Comment: The uncaught type error is suggesting some kind of loop with var i? is your function getCards inside said loop?

Comment: @NickvanderWaal Ill uupdate my post, but that function is being called on document ready

Comment: @NickvanderWaal well it seems the problem might be related with XAMPP, i tried running npm run serve and worked perfectly.

Comment: Laravel only uses your app.js in your public directory, using `npm run dev` you can compile your resources javascript to your public javascript. alternatively you can run `npm run watch` which runs in the background and updates on saves

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to add these cards to your `form` you could also use a jquery ajax shorthand

```
$(function () {    
    $("form").load('/getCards');
});
```

source: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I didn't want to give too many details but the data will go into a select. This was just an ajax test. I'm new with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related with XAMPP or Apache. Since i have been using XAMPP and live server in VS Code for testing with live reload I just decided to use `php artisan serve` and the Ajax call worked. Not sure why.